# Special syntax for function returning function returning function

Tags: scala

I came across following type of function declaration:

```
def fun(): Int => Int => Int = { ..... }
```

How to interpret the type of function `fun`?

Which one of the following two interpretations it indicates?

First interpretation: `fun` is a function returning some function `X` which accepts another function `Y` as a parameter. This function `Y` accepts one integer and returns one integer ; and ultimately the function `X` returns an integer.

```
def fun(): (Int => Int) => Int = { ..... }
```

Second interpretation: `fun` is a function returning some function `X` which accepts an integer as a parameter and returns another function `Y`. This function `Y` accepts an integer and returns an integer.

```
def fun(): Int => (Int => Int) = { ..... }
```

So which one of these interpretations apply in this case?

Comment: It's quite easy to "ask" the scala compiler this question. Maybe you can figure out how?

Comment: Your second interpretation is *almost* correct, except for the fact that `fun` is a method, not a function. So, `fun` is a method with one empty parameter list which returns a function that takes an `Int` which returns a function that takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fun()` is a parameterless method that returns a function with one `Int` argument, that returns another function with one `Int` argument, that returns `Int`.

i.e. your second interpretation:

```
def fun(): Int => (Int => Int) = ???
```

`=>` in Scala is *right associative*, so that operation is grouped from right to left.

Comment: You touched on the distinction between function and method in your explanation, but if you want to be *really* pedantic you also have to account for the difference between a method with zero parameter lists, and a method with one parameter list of zero parameters. "Parameterless method" is somewhat ambiguous in Scala, is that `def meth` (a method with zero parameter lists) or `def meth()` (a method with one parameter list of zero parameters)?